# azure creating an interactive service

Tags: azure

Whats the best way to go about building the following (I'm new to azure so not sure about what approach to take).

- I want a user to be able to start a long running (1-60 minute) 'service' on the server which they
  can then interact with via a web interface.
- The instance of the service will be specific to the user, and live as long as the user
  maintains a connection to it.
- The service has complex state which changes in response to commands given by the user.
- The user will also be able to request state data from the service.
- Most of the time the service will just be waiting for a user
  request.
- Once the user closes the connection to the server it should cease to be.

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with Azure. You can build a Blazor app I guess.

Comment: I want the user to open something akin to a server side shell, the user then interacts with via a single page application (written in Angular). So its kind of a long running 'Function' which maintains a 2 way communication channel, maybe via SignalR. But not sure if there are better Azure constructs to start with.

Comment: Azure Function is not meant to be a long-running communication channel. But Blazor (UI + backend) can satisfy your needs, I guess. It has SignalR and sockets support. If you add some custom functionality and configure DI properly, you can achieve what you need. But I'm not aware of any ready-made thing to satisfy your requirements.

Comment: I did a lot of work with Blazor, its a very nice concept, but I though the implementation of was very poor. They solved the hard problem of getting .Net into a browser, but the way it then interacts with the HTML model is very poor. So no more talk of Blazor! I need this to run server side, and it will be running for a long time as the user will be interacting with it. So sounds like Azure Functions are out, what other Azure constructs would fit the bill, Containers?

Comment: Container is just a way how you deploy your workloads. Usual ASP.NET Web API sounds like a pretty generic solution. You can implement whatever you want. You can use SignalR (which doesn't guarantee the message delivery), sockets (with some library), or gRPC for communication.

Comment: Vladimir Serykh The problem is the application needs to dynamically load assemblies for a given user, and in Asp.Net (especially Asp.Net Core) you can't unload these assemblies. The only other solution is to run the task in a separate process - hence looking into containers.

Comment: Maybe Azure Durable Functions could help?

Comment: Azure Durable Functions look promising, I'll do a bit of prototyping and see where we get to. Thanks